# matrix.postRotate(90) in image rotation

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I can only rotate the image once and when I click on the button again, the image freeze and doesn't rotate. Please help me.

```
try{
    //Bitmap bMap;

    //Get ImageView from layout xml file
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);

    //Decode Image using Bitmap factory.
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);

    //Create object of new Matrix.
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    //set image rotation value to 90 degrees in matrix.
    matrix.postRotate(90);

    //Create bitmap with new values.
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    //put rotated image in ImageView.
    img.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Image Rotated" ;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

    toast.show();

}catch (Exception e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();
    displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Here you have to rotate the already rotated image for the next time, and not the original image, it won't have any effect in rotated the original image again.

Comment: do i have to get the image from the imageView and rotate it again? but how.. can you please show me because i'm new in android. Thank You

Comment: That depends on what exactly are you trying to acheive, getting the image from imageView will be a better option.

Comment: actually i'm importing image from gallery into the imageView which is to perform a rotation and cropping. This is the step of pre-image to text processing which i'm going to use the image rotated and crop to obtain the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
    //Bitmap bMap;

    //Get ImageView from layout xml file
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);

    //Decode Image using Bitmap factory.
    //Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
     Bitmap bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());

    //Create object of new Matrix.
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    //set image rotation value to 90 degrees in matrix.
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);

    int newWidth = bMap.getWidth()/2;
    int newHeight = bMap.getHeight()/2;

    //Create bitmap with new values.
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, matrix, true);

    //put rotated image in ImageView.
    img.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Image Rotated" ;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

    toast.show();

} catch (Exception e) {       
    e.printStackTrace();
    displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
}
```

Wht i've done in ur code is i've created a bitmap from the ImageView for rotation.

Hope this helps..

Comment: wow.. this works.. THANK YOU so much.. i really appreciate this help.. Btw can you please show me how to perform crop action of the image loaded into imageView? this is one of the function to improve the OCR as user will only select the text area and ignore the other part that does not contain any text. Thank You so much

Comment: u mean u want to crop or scale the image before inserting it into the ImageView?

Comment: crop the image after rotate.

Comment: check my edit... **matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);

    int newWidth = bMap.getWidth()/2;
    int newHeight = bMap.getHeight()/2;Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, matrix, true);** ..the image will be cropped to newWidth and newHeight..

Comment: thank you for the crop function. but how to display a crop area (a box) for the user to crop and set the size of the image so that the image can be cropped into any size..

Comment: do you have the solution for that?